# How to get the name of an object itself (not names() )?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the name of any object (say a dataframe) but not the names of its elements. So if my dataframe is:

```
example <- data.frame(a=1, b=2)
```

I would like to be able to get an element like this:

```
element <- "example"
```

Should be easy I think but neither `paste()` nor `names()` nor `toString()` helps. I want to use this inside another function where I also need the dataframe as a dataframe (and I want to use its name to name an excel sheet into which I save it) so I need two elements: the dataframe as well as its name. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are ways to do this, but based on what you say your end goal is, it will probably be easier (and less error prone) to simply put the data frame itself in a named list, e.g. `df_list = list(example = data.frame(a = 1,b = 2))`.

Comment: ha, cool idea! Thanks! I'll give it a shot. After that `names()` should work, right?

Comment: Yes, with the added benefit being that this approach generalizes nicely to more than one data frame. For the record, the other approach would have been `deparse(substitute(example))`, but that's probably needlessly obtuse for what you're trying to do.